# Eurostar or flying London to Paris?

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, weather-and-climate, eurostar

We will be travelling from London to Paris to fly out of Paris same day back to Sydney. Which is better? Eurostar will mean more "changovers" but less affected by weather. Flying will be simpler but as we are flying end January, am worried about the flight getting cancelled if there is bad weather. We MUST meet our flight from CDG-Sydney

Comment: Making the connection is the main concern. I guess the real question is if flights are cancelled due to snow, is the Eurostar usually still working

Comment: @Kascar If that is the real question, then edit it to reflect that.

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried by a flight cancellation due to bad weather. This isn't happening very frequently there to be honest...

Comment: I'd say that if your flight to Paris is cancelled due to the weather, there is a high chance that your flight from Paris is also cancelled, no?

Comment: Which is better is your opinion.  Of you have some factual concerns then please ask them instead.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the comments, the requirement is already clearly stated in the question (last sentence) and strongly implied by the rest of the text too… We tend to react automatically to the word “best” but if you read carefully, that question is neither broad nor opinion-based.

Comment: It's difficult to make a direct comparison without statistics but Eurostar do get cancelled as well (although possibly less often due to the weather) and I am not sure it is *that* common for planes.

Comment: In my experience, if there is bad weather trains are the first ones to be cancelled...at least in Italy.

Comment: Either one *could* unexpectedly be delayed; if you have to be at CDG one day and you start that day 350 km away separated by a body of water then you are inevitably taking a risk. There are plenty of answers here explaining the dangers of split bookings for a trip like this. Neither are *likely to be* delayed, maybe someone can answer by finding statistics for both. Personally I would check my travel insurance cover for such missed connections, and find the minimum gap they would expect for me to be covered. (Or go a few days earlier and visit Paris!)

Comment: best is just don't go to London - have your holidays in France!  :)    The answer is fly - just as @Olielo says.  Both are horrific; the train thing's just a novelty.

Comment: you should absolutely do this - "Or go a few days earlier and visit Paris" as @djr says.  What time of day is the flight in Paris?  If earlyish, I would go the previous day, have a day out, then stay at the ***incredibly convenient*** airport hotels at CDG (there's both an "expensive" one and a "bargain" one) and then get on your long flight in an unhurried fashion.

Comment: Have you already considered changing your flights to go directly from London to Syndey on a single ticket, and cut out the French connection?  There may be a fee, but it might be cheaper than the extra trip from London to Paris, and save time overall.

Comment: @JoeBlow: If you think that both train and plane are horrific maybe travel isn't for you :-)

Comment: as @NateEldredge says it is very likely **cheaper to just change to a London ticket**.

Comment: @JoeBlow I wouldn't be so sure - the UK has very very high long haul flight taxes, which would need adding. There's a reason that lots of UK based fliers book "ex-EU" tickets starting elsewhere in Europe, because it can be a lot cheaper!

Comment: @Gagravarr - I'm sure you're right!  Good one